# google play consoleでの定期購入設定

Tags: google-play, google-play-service, google-play-console

google play consoleで定期購入を設定する場合は先ず、クローズドテストでアプリをリリースしなければなりません。その設定の「アプリのセットアップ」でアプリのアクセス権設定では定期購入がある場合は「アプリのすべてまたは一部の機能が制限される」にチェックを入れることになるそうですが、そうするとその手順を追加することになるそうです。そこで「手順を追加」リンクをクリックすると、手順の名前、ユーザー名とパスワードの入力画面が表示されます。この部分がよくわかりません。自分でサブスクリプションをプログラムする場合は何らかのアクションが必要でしょうが、googleの定期購入システムを利用する場合は手順は不要ではないのでしょうか？
それでは「アクセス制限なくアプリのすべての機能を利用できる」を選択することになるのでしょうか？
もし、そうでないなら「手順の名前」等どのように」設定するのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。